# Remove item from List<T>

Tags: c#

```
List<object> A = new List<object>;
List<object> B = new List<object>;
List<object> C = new List<object>;

C.Add(item);
B.Add(C);
A.Add(B);
```

Finally I have List A than contains List B and List B contains List C.
I want to remove a item from list C.

How can I do this with LINQ or lambda?

Comment: Please state your intentions a little more clearly, **and when downvoted guys, please say why you are downvoting...**

Comment: Why do you use `List<object>` - can `item` be any type?

Answer (score 6):

LINQ is not intended to be used for in-place changes to collections. Use old-school [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) / [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
((List<object>)((List<object>)A[0])[0]).Remove(item);

((List<object>)((List<object>)A[0])[0]).RemoveAll(o => ((MyClass)o).Id == 5);
```

Note: the number of casts required in this code snippet indicates that your way of using *List<T>* may not be optimal for your use case. I strongly recommend you think about specifying a more specific generic argument than *object*.

Comment: it's ok but what if i want to remove all item which contains ID =5 like list.removeAll(dic=>dic.id==5)

Comment: @Shailesh: Then use RemoveAll?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx), [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) and [RemoveRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx).